# How postman complete the OAuth 2.0 flow without actually redirect to the RedirectURL(callbackUrl)?

Tags: react-native, oauth, postman

I am currently trying to integrate MQL5 login to my mobile app using react native.

There are not much example to learn how to integrate it. However, I can successfully use postman to get the access token

[image]

After I fill up the Callback url, client_id and client_secret, I click the request token button.
It will ask me to login MQL5 and after that, postman can get the access token without actually redirect to the Callback Url page. How does postman achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Postman is able to capture the code or token depending on the authorization flow because it handles the request internally. This is different from the typical and recommended flow recommended ([rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-4)) for native apps, where the authentication is handled by a system browser which honors the redirect as request by the authorization endpoint, as can be seen in the first diagram. Instead, Postman recovers the code and uses it to obtain the access token directly from the Resource server.

```
  +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
  |          User Device          |
  |                               |
  | +--------------------------+  | (5) Authorization  +---------------+
  | |                          |  |     Code           |               |
  | |        Client App        |---------------------->|     Token     |
  | |                          |<----------------------|    Endpoint   |
  | +--------------------------+  | (6) Access Token,  |               |
  |   |             ^             |     Refresh Token  +---------------+
  |   |             |             |
  |   |             |             |
  |   | (1)         | (4)         |
  |   | Authorizat- | Authoriza-  |
  |   | ion Request | tion Code   |
  |   |             |             |
  |   |             |             |
  |   v             |             |
  | +---------------------------+ | (2) Authorization  +---------------+
  | |                           | |     Request        |               |
  | |          Browser          |--------------------->| Authorization |
  | |                           |<---------------------|    Endpoint   |
  | +---------------------------+ | (3) Authorization  |               |
  |                               |     Code           +---------------+
  +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-4.1

The request flow in Postman looks like the following instead

```
  +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
  |          User Device          |
  |                               |
  | +--------------------------+  | (3) Authorization  +---------------+
  | |                          |  |     Code           |               |
  | |        Postman           |---------------------->|     Token     |
  | |                          |<----------------------|    Endpoint   |
  | +--------------------------+  | (4) Access Token,  |               |
  |   |             ^             |     Refresh Token  +---------------+
  |   |             |             |
  |   |             |             |
  |   | (1)         | (2)         |
  |   | Authorizat- | Authoriza-  |
  |   | ion Request | tion Code   |
  |   |             |             |        +---------------+
  |   |             |             |        |               |
  |   |             '--------------------->| Authorization |
  |   '------------------------------------|    Endpoint   |
  |                               |        |               |
  |                               |        +---------------+
  +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
```

1. Postman will therefore open a connection to the authorization endpoint and
2. send an HTTP GET request looking like the following.

```
GET /authorize?prompt=login&response_type=code&state=<STATE>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&client_id=<CLIENT_ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL
```

3. The authorization will respond with a login form which Postman will show you.
4. You enter your credentials and Postman replies with a POST request with your credentials.
5. The server sends a response with a 302 redirect such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: <REDIRECT_URI>?code=<CODE>
&state=<STATE>
```

6. Postman now, **instead of redirecting you to the redirect uri** sends a POST request with the code it obtained in the response to the token endpoint with:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: AUTHORIZATION_SERVER
Authorization: Basic <CLIENT_SECRET_IF_CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT>
...
grant_type=authorization_code&code=<CODE>
&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>
```

7. The authorization server responds with the token, a signed base64 encoded json object, which Postman can display for you.

The whole process is described here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1 There are a few variations (implicit flow, confidential or public code flow) on this process for different constraints (SPA, full stack websites, native apps), but they all function similarly.

To conclude, Postman offers the convenience of immediately getting the token and embedding it and is widely use for development purposes. However, many other native apps do similar this, and even websites will handle the authentication in an IFrame which opens the door to malicious use, but also trains users to enter their credentials even in untrusted settings. One of the security advantages of following the suggested workflow is that the application never gets the credentials, and the browser enforces that only the website referred to in the redirect response get to obtain the code. This prevents a malicious app from stealing your credentials (in step 4 above) since the login happens on the authorization server with a trusted user-agent (your browser).